# Eclipse multiple file replace with regular expression

Tags: regex, eclipse, search, replace

I want a regular expression to replace the following kind of line in all the files of my workspace.(`"AbcdEjb"` is the name of the file, it's different in each file)

```
@javax.ejb.Stateless(name = "AbcdEjb")
```

TO:

```
@javax.ejb.Stateless
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
(@javax\.ejb\.Stateless)\(name\s*=\s*[^)]*\)
```

REplacement string:

```
\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lD1wC7/10)